# NDB query by time part of DateTimeProperty

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datetime, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I need to query items that where added at some time of day, ignoring which day. I only save the `DateTime` of when the item was added.

Comparing `datetime.Time` to `DateTimeProperty` gives an error, and DateTimeProperty does not have a `time()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way would be to store the time of day as a separate property.  An int will be fine, you can store it as seconds.  You could do this explicitly (ie set the time property at the same time you set the datetime, or use a computedproperty to automatically set the value.

Answer (score 0):

I've the same problem (more or less) and I think that the only way is build our own date class model.
Something like this:

```
class Date(ndb.model):
   ...
   day = ndb.IntegerProperty()       
   month = ndb.IntegerProperty()
   year = ndb.IntegerProperty()             
   ...

class Anything(ndb.Model):
   ...
   dateTime = ndb.StructuredProperty(Date)
   ...
```

Instead of:

```
class Anything(ndb.Model):
   ...
   dateTime = ndb.DateTimeProperty()
   ...
```

But also I think that we should have other way to do this easier.